# when run "sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full"

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ihave this error

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-indigo-perception but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-indigo-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198167/when-run-%22sudo-apt-get-install-ros-indigo-desktop-full%22/) by [ksmksam](https://answers.ros.org/users/20913/ksmksam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-11-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-11-24**:
I think we'll need some more information. What version of Ubuntu are you running?

**Comment by [ksmksam](https://answers.ros.org/users/20913/ksmksam/) on 2014-11-24**:
14.04
ok this is

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-11-24**:
Try installing only `ros-indigo-desktop`, and see if anything fails. If so, try installing one of the packages that failed. Repeat this and eventually you'll get a more informative error from whatever the offending package is.

**Comment by [ksmksam](https://answers.ros.org/users/20913/ksmksam/) on 2014-11-24**:
ros-indigo-desktop: command not found

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-11-24**:
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop

**Comment by [ksmksam](https://answers.ros.org/users/20913/ksmksam/) on 2014-11-24**:
sorry we still have problem

user@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop
[sudo] password for user:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible sit

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-11-24**:
Do you have the universe and metaverse repositories enabled?

**Comment by [ksmksam](https://answers.ros.org/users/20913/ksmksam/) on 2014-11-25**:
ian new user with upuntu so can you help how ican checked

**Comment by [ksmksam](https://answers.ros.org/users/20913/ksmksam/) on 2014-11-25**:
sorry vertion 12.04 LTS trusty

tom moore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

12.04 is Precise, not Trusty: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases . ROS Indigo is not supported on 12.04/Precise

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2